# How to guarantee order of subscriptions after fromIterable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

This is a simplified example, but basically boils down to this

```
Observable.just(listOfItems)
    .flatMapIterable { it }
    .flatMap {
        doWhatever()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

What I observe, and guess it makes sense, that while the iterable is onNext'ed in order, the `doWhatever()` is subscribed in random order.

**Is there a way I can guarantee order of the doWhatever subscription?** I don't want concatMap, and concatMapEager seems to just order the results, not subscrptions. Artificial delay based on index? (seems to be reliable only with higher delay, anyways magic number - bad)

///

```
private val uploadSchedules = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))

fun upload(request: Request) : Completable {
      Observable.just(request)
         .flatMap { request -> upload(request).subscribeOn(uploadScheduler) }
}

fun upload(requests: List<Request>) : Completable {
      Observable.fromIterable(requests)
         // here the subscriptions order are race-y, I want to want them ordered by the order of the list--|
         .flatMap { request -> upload(request)                                                             |
                        .subscribeOn(uploadScheduler)                                                      |
                        .doOnSubscribe { log(request) }  <-------------------------------------------------|
         }
}

// log outputs:
// request 0
// request 3
// request 4
// request 2
// request 1
// etc, race-y, random order
```

Comment: Use a single threaded scheduler like `Schedulers.single()` or `Schedulers.from()` with a `Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor()` for example. I predict you will then complain that this runs all `doWhatever` one after the other. My response is, why does it even matter which runs first? How do you detect the order? How do you know when the next subscribe can happen?

Comment: I actually use custom Scheduler (not IO) which is fixed to 5 parallel uploads.so atmost 5 should be uploading at a time, and when one finishes, 6th from the waiting should begin to upload. I use scheduler to create this limitation and not the flatMap maxConcurrency because there is also single upload which is another function, so they are in no way related, and globally as I said only 5 should be running. Order of subscription matters for me, first 5 from the list should always be in the first 5 uploading, 6th from the list should never make it into this 5.

Comment: Order of upload completions (doWhatever) doesnt matter. It should know that its done same as concatMap does, the upstream completes. So the listOfItems observable is cold and completable; Its basically a parallel blocking queue situation, I know its hard to understand, hoping its clearer now

Comment: That sounds like `maxConcurrency` to me, but instead of being cold, you run it like a hot service by using a subject to throw in things to upload.

Comment: Yes it is maxConcurrency. However the problem is that its 2 functions, singleUpload, multiUpload, and only way I could limit concurrency in both was to subscribe to commin fixed thread scheduler

Comment: I don't understand. You want to upload 5 at most, right? Why can't multiUpload simply be a N times singleUpload? Should there be an exclusion between a singleUpload and multiUpload so that singleUpload can't progress until all multiUpload have finished?

Comment: Sort of. Basically both function "post requests" to the same parallel queue of width 5 requests. So if multiupload posts 5, and then you post single 1, then the 1 has to wait; same as if single is triggered by user first, and then while its running, user multiuploads 5, then of those 4 are taken, and the 5th waits. Imagine regular blocking java queue, just with "width" of multiple items, or maybe simpler you want atmost 5 parallel uploads going on in the app at one time, overflowing have to be queued and wait for spot to be freed

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B6Mir1cL for clarification

Comment: I'm doubtful this can be done reasonably because the inherent concurrency between uploads of the same batch. Even if you latch onto one with `doOnSubscribe` before `subscribeOn`, scheduling unevennes can always happen so `log(2)` may run before `log(1)`, then the network connections happen in list order. So you'd have to chain uploads by detecting when the network connection was established so that the next in batch can attempt a network connection.

Comment: not sure what you mean with the network, but them being concurrent, or finishing out of order is fine. I just need the subscriptions to happen in order, so the 6th+ can be put on the backpressure queue by the fixed scheduler etc. Currently I only added .delaySubscription(index * magic number), but I'm obviously not happy about it

Comment: so basically you're saying that while I could get single thread to call the subscribes synchronously, doesn't mean that they'd get run in that order? not even with maxConcurrency=1? I thought the overflow queue is fair

Comment: Single threaded scheduler or maxConcurrency of 1 can get you that ordered execution at the cost of having no more than 1 upload at a time. Otherwise you can get reorderings. I still don't understand why you can't use a serialized Subject and `onNext` the download instructions, then have flatMap with maxConcurrency do the rest?

Comment: @urSus Any solution?